# Filter an complex array with multiple criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

```
var sd = {
"searchData": [
    {
        "description": "ISU ISU",
        "tags": {
            "portfolio": [
                "p1",
                "p2",
                "p3"
            ],
            "industry": [
                "i1",
                "i2",
                "i3"
            ]
        },

    },
    {
        "description": null,
        "tags": {
            "portfolio": [
                "p1",
                "p2",
                "p3"
            ],
            "industry": [
                "i1",
                "i4",
                "i5"
            ]
        },
        {
        "description": null,
        "tags": {
            "portfolio": [
                "p4",
                "p5",
                "p6"
            ],
            "industry": [
                "i1",
                "i2",
                "i3"
            ]
        },
    }
]
```

}

I will get this data from a api. 
I want to filter the above with portfolio value of p1 and industry with i1.

I tried using filter but not able to get the required result.
I cannot use other libraries like loadash or undersore. I have to do it from nomal ES6 methods.

Comment: Unable to understand your query

Comment: Sry.. this is my first Q on stackoverflow.... I'm not totally aware of how to use it.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: "I tried using filter" ... please show that try.

Comment: Expected output is to get objects with Portfolio having value p1 and industry having value i1..ie; first two objects inside searchData

Comment: Can you paste the output in your question *as an array* please? e.g. Give us A, B, and the logic from A to B. Use the [edit] link to edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter method. Not sure how you used it, but this is how it should look.

```
sd.searchData.filter(obj => {
    if (!obj.tags.industry.includes("i1"))
        return false;
    if (!obj.tags.portfolio.includes("p1"))
        return false;
    return true;
})
```

Or a one liner:

```
sd.searchData.filter(obj => obj.tags.industry.includes("i1") && obj.tags.portfolio.includes("p1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array with the search criteria and filter the array by taking the key and value for a check.

```js
var data = { searchData: [{ description: "ISU ISU", tags: { portfolio: ["p1", "p2", "p3"], industry: ["i1", "i2", "i3"] } }, { description: null, tags: { portfolio: ["p1", "p2", "p3"], industry: ["i1", "i4", "i5"] } }, { description: null, tags: { portfolio: ["p4", "p5", "p6"], industry: ["i1", "i2", "i3"] } }] },
    search = [["portfolio", "p1"], ["industry", "i1"]],
    result = data.searchData.filter(({ tags }) => search.every(([k, v]) => tags[k].includes(v)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sd = {
    searchData : [
        {
            "description": "ISU ISU",
            "tags": {
                "portfolio": [
                    "p1",
                    "p2",
                    "p3"
                ],
                "industry": [
                    "i1",
                    "i2",
                    "i3"
                ]
            },

        },
        {
            "description": null,
            "tags": {
                "portfolio": [
                    "p1",
                    "p2",
                    "p3"
                ],
                "industry": [
                    "i1",
                    "i4",
                    "i5"
                ]
            },
        },
        {
            "description": null,
            "tags": {
                "portfolio": [
                    "p4",
                    "p5",
                    "p6"
                 ],
                "industry": [
                    "i1",
                    "i2",
                    "i3"
                ]
            },
        }
    ]
    };

console.log(sd.searchData.filter((element) => {
    return element.tags.portfolio.includes('p1') && element.tags.industry.includes('i1')
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const sd = {searchData : [{"description": "ISU ISU","tags": {"portfolio": ["p1","p2","p3"],"industry": ["i1","i2","i3"]},},{"description": null,"tags": {"portfolio": ["p1","p2","p3"],"industry": ["i1","i4","i5"]},},{"description": null,"tags": {"portfolio": ["p4","p5","p6"],"industry": ["i1","i2","i3"]},}]};
const result = sd.searchData.filter(({tags}) => tags.industry.includes('i1') && tags.portfolio.includes('p1'));

console.log(result);
```